# Не работает выпадающее меню CSS

Tags: html, css

Не работает выпадающее меню, помогите, пожалуйста. Только учусь, ошибок, наверное, много.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

nav {
  padding: 67px 0px 120px 930px;
  margin: 0px;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0 0 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 80px 0px 0;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18x;
  line-height: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  border: 3px #fff;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: inherit;
}

nav ul ul li {
  min-width: 70px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТЬ</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Транспорт и логистика</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Строительство и монтаж</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Оптово-розничная торговля</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: В будущем используйте классы для тегов, а то в коде можно запутаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения конкретно вашей задачи, если не переделывать, достаточно добавить строку

```
margin-top: 20px;
```

В стиль `nav ul li`.

Т.е. должно получится вот так:

```
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

А так же подготовил для вас простенький пример. Может пригодится.

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.menu>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

ul.menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu>li>a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

ul.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  top: 36px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

ul.submenu>li {
  display: block;
}

ul.submenu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.submenu>li>a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

ul.menu>li:hover>ul.submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href=#>Menu</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href=#>Submenu</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Submenu</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Submenu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3):

Исправил

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0 0 0px;
  display: inline-grid;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 80px 0px 0;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18x;
  line-height: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  border: 3px #fff;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul ul li {
  min-width: 70px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТЬ</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Транспорт и логистика</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Строительство и монтаж</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Оптово-розничная торговля</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```